# Search a string to see if a word occurs more than once

Tags: c#, streamreader

I need to check if the given word is contained in a line inside the path, and print it. Here is my code:

```
using (StreamReader reading = new StreamReader(path))
{
   string user= Console.ReadLine();
   string line = user;
   Console.WriteLine();
   while ((line = reading.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
       if (line.Contains(user))
       {
          Console.WriteLine(line);
       }
    }
 }
```

This is working, but if in the stream the word is found twice it gives two strings as an output. How can i check if the word is found twice?

Comment: What you want to do if the word is contained multiple times?

Comment: "This is working, but if in the stream the word is found twice it gives two strings as an output. How can i check if the word is found twice?"  Didn't you say it was working?  What do you want to happen if it's found twice?

Comment: Do you just want the count of how many times the word appears in the file?

Comment: i need to check how many times the given user appears: if it appears just one time, i get a simple output. but if there is more than one user with the same name, i have to choose just one, with another selection. My question was about the checking itself!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display the lines with the user and display the total count of how many lines contains `user`, you can easily do this with some LINQ:

```
var linesWithUser = File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(x => x.Contains(user)).ToList();

//Prints the count
Console.WriteLine(linesWithUser.Count);

//Prints all the lines that contain the user, maybe do other things...
foreach(var line in linesWithUser)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Just missing the lines where the user was found since OP is printing them all

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
bool ContainsWordMultipleTimes(string word, string input)
{
    var regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", word), 
                          RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return regex.Matches(input).Count > 1;
}
```

Or even extend `string` like this:

```
public static class StringWordsExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsMultipleTimes(this string input, string word)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", word),
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return regex.Matches(input).Count > 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put your counting outside of the while, like this:

```
int count = 0;
    string line = null;
    while ((line = reading.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(user))
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(user +" found " + count +" time");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(user + " not found!");
    }
```